# Asp.Net MVC3 Ado.Net Entity Data Model timeout error - Entity Framework Command execution timeout error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

First let me clarify, I searched stackoverflow solutions for this, and whatever I found didn't resolve this error in my situation. Users keep getting this error every now and than and when they re-query or refresh the page data appear fine without error. This behavior is certainly irritating the users even if they get a user-friendly message instead of Asp.net YSOD.

Complete error message:
    *System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection*)

To give a brief overview about the application: It's a .Net MVC3 application. There is separate project for Business logic and separate project for UI (Controller and Views etc..). Business logic project contains Data layer which is ADO.NET Entity Data Model (I believe entity framework 4.1). The EF contains only Sql Server Store Procedures (there are no tables/views etc..). All communications to the database happen through SPs function imports. The business project queries the SPs and returns IQueriable type business object, which eventually we use in controller and return as JSON objects to the jQuery AJAX call. Our SQL serve DB is 2012.

One solution resolves this issue ***temporarily*** is when I restart the IIS 7.

What I have tried so far and have not been able to resolve this issue:

1. Increased EF Command Execution timeout.
2. used below using pattern

   using (DbContext context = new DBContext())
   {
     context.Connection.Open();
       //All EF code goes here.
     context.Connection.Close();
   }
3. Updating the model from DB and recreating all the function imports fresh.
4. Database side tuning up to improve the query performance.
5. Some more...unable to recall right now.

Please let me know if you need any other information. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to open connection like that? Perhaps its may be because of an old entity framework version, but anyway, plz check if you can write code like `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`. See if you can use this function

Comment: I am not sure what you meant when you say "Do you really need to open connection like that?" BTW, can you give me some code example of context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand. As I mentioned, in the business layer project, the constructors of each component initializes EF/database connection.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx) for example